# can we transfer or share paid apk from One device to another device from Google play

Tags: android, google-play

Hi i have create one paid application i want Upload it in Google play but i m confused about Google play server that when we Perches paid application then .apk file downloading then installing i just want to know that can we share or transfer  that .apk file or package what ever downloading from Google play  one device to another device please confirm me so that i can upload our paid application in Google play .

second can re-install that .apk after 1 year because the application access is only for 1 year after they will have Perches again . please help me in this Query .

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that I downloaded your application. I use it for some time. There are other application available in google play store that can make apk files of installed application like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neoengineerss.apkcreatorfree) one. After you have the apk file you can share it upload it and distribute it. so you should use some mechanism (usually internet based) to prevent application from running if it is not downloaded from play store.

Comment: I just want to Know that after perches application some file is donwlaoding right can share or send to another p i want to know about it ?

Comment: share that is as attachment i mean to say that ..so that other user can install that paid application i want to know about it

Comment: users can only share link to your application from play store

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pecsaadiciavin.taxmannpaid  Suppose this is paid application  i have Perches it some file first downloading i want to know about it that can share that file from one device to another device

Comment: .apk file can be distributed by anyone, and to anyone; as attachment, or as "mirrored" download link, etc.  You have to do some checking to prevent the usage if it's "pirated". Edit: some file managers with root access can easily get the .apk file, and it can be transferred as easy as using bluetooth.